# How to import a const exported as a default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, default

There is a line in my project code that goes like this,

```
const variableName = { ... }

export default variableName
```

Is the `variableName` written correctly in the first place? Shouldn't its be either a

```
export const variableName = { ... } // import { variableName } from './file'
```

OR

```
export default variableName = { ... } // import variableName from './file'
```

What is the right way to import this in another file?

```
import { variableName } from 'file'
```

OR

```
import variableName from './file'
```

PS - I've looked at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-default#), [blogs](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f) as well but they do not talk about exporting a const variable as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all correct ways to export.

if it is exported as default:

```
import myComponent from '...'
```

if it is a named export (`export x;`)

```
import {x} from '...';
// OR
import {x as y} from '...';
console.log(y);
```

`export const x = /* ... */;` is just a shorthand for

```
const x = /* ... */;
export x;
```

this shorthand is not available for default export, you **can't** write:

```
export default const x = {};
```

[Why Is `Export Default Const` invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261225/why-is-export-default-const-invalid)