# Setting vue component data from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The desired behaviour:

/component.vue

```
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      rowData: []
    }
  } 
}
```

I would like to define the data from a vue component in a external file.

> error: rowData is not defined.

/component.vue

```
import datas from './options.js'

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      datas
    }
  } 
}
```

/options.js

```
export default datas = {
  rowData: []
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
import datas from './options.js'

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      ...datas
    }
  } 
}
```

or:

```
import datas from './options.js'

export default {
  data(){
    return datas
  } 
}
```

if no more data is added.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `const` keyword in your options.js , try to add it like :

```
  const datas = {
  rowData: []
 };
 export default datas;
```

and in your compponent.vue :

```
   import datas from './options.js'

  export default {
      data(){
         return{
               datas:datas
             }
           } 
         }
```

Comment: Actually `export default const` doesn't seems to be valid - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: yeah but the OP is naming that object so she should add `let` or `const`

Comment: but this is not valid syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261225/why-is-export-default-const-invalid/51329869