# Prefer default export.eslint(import/prefer-default-export) for constant

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am dealing with constant file and having just one constant object in that file. I am facing trouble with ESLINT error checking part.

Constant file name :- `constant.js`

```
export const myObject = {
    const1:'hello world',
    const2:'new world'
}
```

Getting an eslint error `Prefer default export.eslint(import/prefer-default-export)`

Here constants are not allow to export default( only class and function are allow to export)

Environment information

ESLint plugin version :- 1.9.0

Here, how do i create and export constant without eslint error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either define the object up front, and then export it:

```
const myObject = {
  const1:'hello world',
  const2:'new world'
};
export default myObject;
```

Or just export the object expression:

```
export default {
  const1:'hello world',
  const2:'new world'
};
```

The second case doesn't have `const` anywhere, but the default export isn't reassignable anyway.

> Here constants are not allow to export default( only class and function are allow to export)

The problem was not that you can't `export default` a `const` (though you can't do so in [one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261225/why-is-export-default-const-invalid)), but that the linting rule is pushing you to actually use `export default` (rather than a named export, as you were doing), since you only have a single export.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, don't you think recommendations for constant export should be improve at this point ?

Comment: What do you mean, "should be improve"? The error is *pretty* self-explanatory already, what were you thinking of?

Comment: As per error, if i export with like `export default const myObject` then another rule has been violated and it says "export default is use with classes or function only". So here, i would suggesting to improve error message for constant default if possible.

Comment: Yeah, though that's not really a linting rule, but just how the syntax is required to be *everywhere*, see the link in the answer. I don't know the reason for it either, seems a bit strange