# Why does export default throw an error when running expo app in browser?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a component where I use export default:

```
export default CategoryCard = (props) => {
    const {name, color, onPress } = props

    return (  ..my code
```

and so the import statement is `import CategoryCard`.

When I try to run in the browser using Expo Client the browser returns error 
"ReferenceError: CategoryCard is not defined"

if I change 
`export default CategoryCard` to `export const CategoryCard` 
and change `import CategoryCard` to `import { CategoryCard }` then things work fine in browser.

I understand the difference between the statements and I am not overly concerned here as this is a native app that won't run in a browser ultimately - but I'm just curious for my own learning what is going on here and why the broswer doesn't like the export default.

Comment: Some useful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261225/why-is-export-default-const-invalid

Comment: What's surprising is that there's any environment *not* giving you the error. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that's allowing you to do the version witout `const` (or `let`), then it's implemented modules incorrectly. The line

```
export default CategoryCard = (props) => {
```

says "Assign this value (an arrow function) to the **already existing** variable `CategoryCard` and export the value as the default export of this module." Modules are always in strict mode, so if you don't have a declaration for `CategoryCard` anywhere, that's a reference error. (Without strict mode, you can create globals by assigning to undeclared variables, but it's a Bad Idea™. :-) )

Since modules are always strict, you need that `const` or `let` in there:

```
export default const CategoryCard = (props) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```

The browser giving you the error is correct, because it's a ReferenceError (in strict mode) to assign to an undeclared identifier.

---

Which isn't to say that you always have to have `const` or `let` or `function` or `class` with an `export`. You don't, you can export the result of an arbitrary expression as the default export. This is valid code, for instance:

```
export default 6 * 7;
```

So if you had `CategoryCard` declared elsewhere, your export would be valid:

```
let CategoryCard;
export default CategoryCard = (props) => {
```

I'm not suggesting that of course, just pointing out that it's valid. :-)